# Odoo hide breadcrumble

Tags: css, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, bootstrapping

I am trying to hide breadcrumb [like in this example:](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-change-link-color-91814)

My code:

my_model_view.xml

```
    <template id="assets_frontend" name="my_model assets" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" >
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href="/my_model/static/src/css/style.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>


</data>
```

style.css

```
.breadcrumb > li {
  display: none !important;
}
.breadcrumb > .active {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and **openerp**.py:

```
"data": [
    "my_model_view.xml",
],
```

After that I restarted servise, saw that my_model_view.xml was loaded but nothing happens. Breadcumb of my model is still visible. No errors I don't know where is the problem.

**UPDATE:**

*I found the solution. The problem was with this file: my_model_view.xml.
New my_model_view.xml version:*

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="my_model assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" >
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="/my_model/static/src/css/style.css"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: You can try with hiding class of breadcrumbs from js file.

Comment: Do you have an exmaple. It will help me a lot.

Comment: I've update your code. Refer them and check your css file path as well b'caz your code is perfect.

Comment: Its in backend_assets

Comment: I changed my_model_view.xml into:         <template id="assets_backend" name="my_model assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" > but nothing happens :(