# Odoo modify css only for my app

Tags: html, css, odoo, odoo-9, bootstrapping

I was trying to hide breadcrumbs. I did it but I hide it for all Odoo apps:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934874/odoo-hide-breadcrumble?noredirect=1#comment78832723_45934874)

style.css

```css
.breadcrumb > li {
  display: none !important;
}
.breadcrumb > .active {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I was trying something like that but nothing..

style.css

```css
.breadcrumb.my_model > li {
  display: none !important;
}
.breadcrumb > .active.my_model {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Is it a possibility hide it only in my `my_model` app?

I am talking about this part:

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with odoo but I am sure you have to find some class that descriminate you app.A block of `html` code could help us .

Comment: No. It doesn't work by this way. But you can use `t`, `<p>` or `<div>` and set a new class for the fields in your app.

Comment: I want to use it not for the field but to hide bradcrumb. Look, I edited my question. Or I should expand the template where are placed breadcrumble and try toreplace breadcrumb class

Comment: There is a js widget called "ControlPanel" where the breadcrumb is handled. Maybe you can change the behaviour there.

Comment: I am studying control_panel.js I see the problem that I can't there set a model name by which I can hide it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already exists an option that you can pass to the action manager named `clear_breadcrumbs`. You have to pass `clear_breadcrumbs=true` in your action's [options](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/web/static/src/js/action_manager.js#L533).

Comment: I was trying to use it in my python code: return {
      'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
      'name': _('Sales Order'),
      'res_model': 'purchase.request',
      'res_id': data.get('purchase_request_id'),
      'view_type': 'form',
      'view_mode': 'form',
      'target': 'current',
      'clear_breadcrumbs': true,
      'nodestroy': True, }